# How to combine JUnit annotations into a custom annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, junit5, junit-jupiter

(Using OpenJDK-13 and JUnit5-Jupiter)

The problem is that my unit tests each make use of a not-small JUnit annotation system, something like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("myorg.ccrtest.testlogic.DataProviders#standardDataProvider")
@Tags({@Tag("ccr"), @Tag("standard")})
```

This makes test authoring a little tedious, test code a little long and of course, when a change is needed, it's a chore!

Was wondering if I could create my own JUnit annotation: `@CcrStandardTest`, which would imply all of the annotations above?

I also tried shifting the annotations up in the class definition (hoping they would then apply to all methods of the class), but the compiler says no: "@ParameterizedTest is not applicable to type"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a [composed annotation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-meta-annotations):

> JUnit Jupiter annotations can be used as *meta-annotations*. That means that you can define your own *composed annotation* that will automatically *inherit* the semantics of its meta-annotations.

For example:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;

@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("myorg.ccrtest.testlogic.DataProviders#standardDataProvider")
@Tag("ccr")
@Tag("standard")
public @interface CcrStandardTest {}
```

You would then place the composed annotation on your test method:

```java
@CcrStandardTest
void testFoo(/* necessary parameters */) {
  // perform test
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. However, I am not out of the woods yet :( When I created my meta-tag and used it in a prototype test method, JUnit execution says: "no tests were found". When I added (a)Test directly to the test method, it "found" the test (and executed), but IDE suggests "suspicious combination (a)Test and parameterized source". I know (a)Parameterized test implies (a)Test - but why JUnit doesn't consider (a)CcrStandardTest as a (a)Test?

Comment: OK, upon further analysis, it's because I didn't apply (a)Retention and (a)Target, which you suggested... Tests are running now but I wish JUnit documentation explained (a)Target and (a)Retention! Could you please elaborate with a few words? :) Created new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339277

Comment: I added imports to this answer to hopefully make things more clear. I'll explain more about `@Retention` and `@Target` in your other Q&A.